# Retrieve only needed info from MySQl or Filter it once retrieved in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

If I have about 250 entries with 6 columns in a MySQL database, and I want a "dynamic" filtering to show entries depending on the checkboxes checked off, is it better to retrieve them all and then hide some results via jquery or do a PHP/MySQL query every time a checkbox is checked?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you try and measure?

Comment: Why? This isn't about latency only, but server strain and also programming practices that experienced professionals surely have an opinion about.

Comment: Experienced professionals like when people put some effort into the question. Your question would look better in the form "I want to do X. I did it this way and it took N seconds per request. Another way takes M seconds. What do you suggest?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is 2 questions one must answer before proceeding!

Will the end-time user filter the view a few times (like say they reload the results 2 - 7 times)?

Will the behind-the-scenes data change regularly?

Case 1:  Yes to filters, no to changing data

- Get all the data, cache it in hidden divs, and perform a javascript (jQuery) filtering algorithm to reduce server cost

Case 2:  Yes to filters, yes to changing data.

- The data better be retrieved and sorted by the back end $query (`WHERE`) and retrieve the data and update the display via ajax/javascript

Case 3: No to filters, Yes to changing data.

- A litter different than above.  You could load the data on the page and use a page refreshing system (simplest i think to get started).

Case 4:  No and No

- Just load it either via ajax, back end with php.  You decide.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your answer. By 'changing regularly', would once a week classify as a regular change?

Comment: Nah.  I was thinking more like a social network.  If the user logs on, performs some queries (different views) and gets off in the matter of 10 minutes and the possibility of data changing is < 1% (in your case its MUUUUCH less) then i would not worry about doing a caching system.  Its clearly an overkill!  But if you would like to practice `Computer Science` then your goal would be to make it elegant and efficient.  Then i would do cache (more for fun then required).

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to know is to do it and measure it. But my guess would be it's better to get all the info and then manipulate it with jQuery as you suggest. A round-trip to the database is often quite expensive so better get as much data as you need while you are there.

Answer (score 1):

1] if database is heavy read and slight write and updates are not critical (criticality means you need latest update) then cache the query and use divs.

2] if database is either heavy write or updates are critical then you must query each time.